# Android Emulator won't launch, no console output or errors

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to run the Android emulator on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine.  I have installed the Android SDK, JDK, Eclipse, and the Android plugins for Eclipse.  From the SDK Manager, I have installed the Android SDK Tools, as well as all of the files for Android 4.1 (API 16).

From Eclipse, when I want to open the emulator I select the AVD Manager and click on a device that I have created.  The AVD Manager says that the virtual device is a valid device.  When I launch the machine, a box pops up that says "Starting Android Emulator," and there is a loading bar right below it.  The bar will get to about 95%, and then the box will disappear and nothing will happen.  There will be no errors and no messages in the console output box in Eclipse.  I get similar behavior when I try to launch the emulator by running an app from Eclipse.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK to a new directory, as well as downloading a different version of Eclipse (I am currently using Eclipse Java EE, earlier I was using Eclipse Classic 4.2).  I also tried downloading the API 15 platform and using that as a virtual device, and I still have the same issues.

I have checked my task manager, and the only new process that is ever created is adb.exe, and this only happens when I try to run my app, but not when I start the emulator on its own.

Any idea what might be causing this, or what methods I might use to troubleshoot this that will actually give me some kind of error message, rather than just disappearing and not doing anything?  Thanks.

Edit: When I try to run the emulator from the AVD Manager directly, I get the same behavior as when running through Eclipse (loading box pops up, then disappears, then nothing).

Comment: What happens when you run the AVD manager directly instead of from Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BlueStacks emulator instead standart. It work much more faster and reliably. You can download it from http://bluestacks.com. After installing reboot the system. I think all be fine.

Comment: Does this allow for emulating the entire Android OS, or just individual apps?  I am trying to make an app to interact with the API of another app so I would ideally like to install both apps for testing and see how it works within Android.

Comment: BluStacks allow to emulate any android application, that can be emulated on standart android emulator(it's analog of standart emulator but much more faster and handy in use).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Enabling Host GPU emulation worked for me.